# Cannot get InputStream from URL inside AsyncTask after application closes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have this simple AyncTask in which I fetch bytes from URL:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MyObject>> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;
private FragmentActivity context;

public MyAsyncTask(FragmentActivity activity) {
    context = activity;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("...");
    this.dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<MyObject> doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    ArrayList<MyObject> objects = null;

    try {
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return null;
        }
        String line;
        objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        MyObject mo = new MyObject();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Process data
        }

        reader.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }

    return objects;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MyObject> data) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (data == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else {

    }

}
}
```

The problem with this code is that it works only first time when application opens. After I close my application, this doesn't work anymore. The problem appears on this line:

```
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
```

I simply cannot get `getInputStream();` to work again after I close my application. After my AsyncTask starts again, it just shows progress bar and stays there. With LogCat I found out it stops at that line, like the stream is still opened.

What could be a problem? I don't receive any exceptions, only this warning when I close application:

```
IInputConnectionWrapper showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you are missing to close your connection like : connection.close().

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try calling disconnect in the catch block? Because if some exception happens, the Url connection remains not disconnected.

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    return null;
} finally {
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but `HttpURLConnection` doesn't have `close()`, only `disconnect();`

Answer (score 0):

This problems occur when the input connection has not been closed. Check whether you closed the input connection using :

```
connection.close()
```

Comment: Thank you but `HttpURLConnection` doesn't have `close()`, only `disconnect();`